# Highlighting PsiElement with multiple children in Intellij plugin

Tags: intellij-plugin

In my language  syntax, my strings can contain tokens (macros). I therefore need to lex a string in its parts:

```
 '"'  parts * '"'
```

This gives me a PSI tree of:

```
Value(value)(14,33)
  StringElement(string)(14,33)
    PsiElement(QUOTE_START)('"')(14,15)
    PsiElement(PART)('....')(15,32)
    PsiElement(QUOTE_END)('"')(32,33)
```

I want to give the whole string a highlight color. However, my syntax highlighter is never consulted for the `StringElement`. (It works fine for its constituents).

Is PSI limited to only nodes that are directly parsed by the Lexer?

Answer (score 2):

The [`SyntaxHighlighterBase`](https://upsource.jetbrains.com/idea-ce/file/idea-ce-8f0275fd7faaeafdb8900147eab3d256fe4221cb/platform/editor-ui-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/fileTypes/SyntaxHighlighterBase.java?_ga=2.27437244.1825803281.1637911117-245428096.1606562480) (which I assume you are using) can indeed only highlight lexer tokens. You specify which tokens to highlight using `getTokenHighlights`, which can highlight the tokens returned by the lexer you supply with `getHightlightingLexer` (both functions come from the `SyntaxHighlighter` interface).

If you want to highlight your composite `StringElement`, you'll have to resort to using an [annotator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/syntax-highlighting-and-error-highlighting.html#annotator). You can implement the [`Annotator`](https://upsource.jetbrains.com/idea-ce/file/idea-ce-24dca6ee4dd9930c75bdc09b69cf4353dcecb46e/platform/analysis-api/src/com/intellij/lang/annotation/Annotator.java) interface directly, annotating your elements using a silent annotation, for example:

```kotlin
private fun annotateElement(element: PsiElement, attributesKey: TextAttributesKey, holder: AnnotationHolder) {
    holder.newSilentAnnotation(HighlightSeverity.INFORMATION)
        .range(element)
        .textAttributes(attributesKey)
        .create()
}
```